# Printing leading zeroes for hexadecimal in C

Tags: c, linux, formatting

I am trying to print the results of an MD5 hash to the console and it is working for the most part. To ensure correctness, I used an online MD5 calculator to compare results. Most of the characters are the same, but a few are missing in mine and they are are all leading zeroes.

Let me explain. The result is a 16 byte unsigned char *. I print each of these bytes one by one. Each byte prints TWO characters to the screen. However, if the first character out of the two is a zero, it does not print the zero.

```
printk("%x", result);
```

Result is of type unsigned char*. Am I formatting it properly or am I missing something?

Comment: It's not even remotely similar to that other question, since the other question _prohibits_ printf family of functions and this one requires it.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Use `"%02x"`.

The two means you always want the output to be (at least) two characters wide.

The zero means if padding is necessary, to use zeros instead of spaces.

Answer (score 6):

`result` is a pointer, use a loop to print all the digits:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
   printf("%02x", result[i]);
}
```

Comment: I left out the [i] in my post by accident. Thanks for pointing it out though!